# vagrantのboxのダウンロードが出来ない: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60

Tags: vagrant

vagrantで仮想マシンを起動しようとしたら、boxがなかったので、'bento/centos-6.8'をダウンロードしていると、

> OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60

というエラーが出て、正常にダウンロードできません。解決方法を教えてください。

```
MacBook-Air:MyCentOS aonoryousuke$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'bento/centos-6.8' could not be found. Attempting to 
find and install...
default: Box Provider: virtualbox
default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'bento/centos-6.8'
default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/bento/centos-6.8   
==> default: Adding box 'bento/centos-6.8' (v2.3.4) for provider: 
virtualbox
default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/bento/boxes/centos- 
6.8/versions/2.3.4/providers/virtualbox.box
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60
```

Comment: マルチポスト: https://teratail.com/questions/118458

Comment: macOS のバージョン、`openssl version` の結果、`vagrant version` の結果を追記して下さいませんか？　本文の下の「編集」から自由に追記できます。

Answer (score 1):

途中で失敗するときは何度か試してみましょう。恒久的な問題でなければ、そのうちダウンロードは完了します。

Vagrant はダウンロード中の Box を `~/.vagrant.d/tmp/box<何かのハッシュ値?>` に書き込みますが、Ctrl+c で中断したり途中で失敗してもそのまま放置します。そして同じ Box を取得しようとしたときは、前回ダウンロードした分以降からダウンロードを再開します。(`curl`(1) の `--continue-at -` を利用している）

Answer (score 0):

[`SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/f1b97da1fd90cf3935eafedc8df0d0165cb75f2f/doc/man3/SSL_get_error.pod#return-values) は何かしらの I/O エラーが起こったとき、特にソケット関係のエラーが起こったときに出るエラーです。更に macOS において [`errno 60`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-201.5/osfmk/libsa/errno.h.auto.html) はタイムアウトを意味します。つまりこのエラーはソケット I/O のタイムアウトが原因と考えられます。

`bento/centos-6.8` を提供するサーバーは広く使われており、現在も動いています。このため、以下の対処法が考えられます。

- `vagrantcloud.com` に対して接続できていること、接続速度が殊更に遅くないことを確認する。
- `vagrant up` を何回か繰り返す。
- ダウンロード関係の一時ファイルなどが格納されている `~/.vagrant.d/tmp/*` を削除し、再度 `vagrant up` を試す。
- `vagrant up` する時間帯を変えてみる。Vagrant の[これ](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8434)や[この](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/5319) issue を見るに、VagrantCloud 自体への接続がとても遅い地域・時間があるようです。

Comment: これ実践したのですが、出来なかったです...

Answer (score 0):

私も、同様のエラーに見舞われました。
vagrant upを3回繰り返して成功しました。